# Can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/websocket

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, http-status-code-404, spring-websocket

please someone help me im fighting with this for 4 days straight, looked up through every tutorial but i can't get it to work. I want to establish connection between front-end Angular and the back-end Server, i want when the user successfuly log in the web-socket to connect and return his wallet amount from the database. For now i just want to try test return a simple string just to check if everything is good but i can't do it, i have never dealed with WebSockets before..

This is my WebSocketConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/wallet");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4200/")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

This is my WalletSocketHandler Controller

```
@Controller
public class WalletSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/test")
    @SendTo("/wallet/test")
    public String test(String message) {
        System.out.println("TEST MESSAGE - SUCCESSFUL");
        System.out.println("TEST MESSAGE - SUCCESSFUL");
        return "Received message: " + message;
    }
}
```

And finally this is the service in Angular

```
export class WebSocketService {
  private ws = new WebSocketSubject('ws://localhost:8080/websocket');
  constructor() {}
  
  connectToSocket() {
    console.log('CONNECT TO SOCKET EXECUTED');
    console.log(this.ws); // When i tried printing it, it shows false object with false values, no idea..
    this.ws.subscribe()
    
    this.ws.next({type: '/wallet/test', payload: 'Test message'});
    this.ws.subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Received response: ', response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('FITALITY MORTAL KOMBAT');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I keep getting 'can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/websocket.' and i don't know what to do anymore.

When i browse localhost:8080/websocket - I get 'Welcome to SocketJS'
I tried almost everything even switching to nxg-socket-io but with no success.

Comment: Hello, I can't help you with websocket configuration. Just wanted to say that it could be implemented much easier with REST endpoint and Spring Boot MVC Starter. You would be ready not in 4 days but in 4 hours. Websockets are necessary when client and sever need to be connected all the time like for exchanging messages with a queue. REST is for one off call from client to server to get (or set) some information from the database. Just like in your case.

Comment: Hello i understand, thank you for your response but im trying to make gambling website for my portfolio and i need to keep real time data about the user's wallet so that when he makes a bet it gets updated on both ends :)

Comment: Can you add error logs , what issue are you facing during the connection?

Comment: Hello i dont have errors, it just doesnt work..

Comment: you have configured STOMP over websocket in your spring application, and enabled SockJS. so you can use SockJS and StompJS libraries to connect and pass the messages. Instead you can remove `.withSockJs()` and use RxStomp lib to directly to pass the messages to spring server